# Capturing traffic on wire from an endpoint

Tags: wireshark, tap

Say I have my computer connected to a router with an Ethernet cable. How do I capture all packets on the wire? (possibly with using some kind of hardware that's much cheaper than another computer)

I want to do this to see if Wireshark (running on the computer) shows all traffic or if there is some firmware that hides some packets from it.

Comment: Wireshark will show all packets sent on your computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wireshark will display packets for you, but it only shows the packets sent or received by the computer.  If you want to see packets going to other computers, then you will either need an Ethernet hub, or configure your router to send you a copy of all packets.  Commercial routers can do this, but consumer grade cannot (Note that consumer devices are also off-topic here).